# MvvmCross how to open viewmodel with no back stack or restart the app

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, .net-standard

my app has a helper service which create and `refreshtokenhandler` with each request before handling the request which try to execute the request if access token is valid, otherwise it generate a new token using refresh token.

the problem is the system can revoke the refresh/access tokens (eg. logout everywhere) and when this happens the user must be redirected to the login screen to generate new tokens. but `mvvmcross` can't navigate to `viewmodel` from the service without being able to return back

Comment: Yes, any library does not contain everything you need for your app. You have to code it by yourself. That is what a programmer does: Writing code

Comment: I know but i don't know were to start i been research this and i think i need to implement a custom presenter but i have no idea how to access back stack from there. it's my second project in xamarin and my first in `mvvmcross` i'm not yet familiar with `mvvmcross`

Comment: To me it sounds you need a NavigationService which will handle the  navigation

Comment: i guess you are right i dunno why it didn't cross in my mind lol. i will extend the default navigation service and keep track of `navigate` and `close` methods one that store a viewmodel and one to remove from a list and when needed i will just close all stored viewmodels. thank you @sir rufo have a nice day.

Comment: I recommend you to create a custom PresentationHint to clear the backstack (https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/presenters/view-presenters?scroll=504#requesting-presentation-changes). Please be aware you'll need to request it from your Core and then handle it in all your platforms.